# Is it possible to add a UIBarButtonItem besides a UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uisegmentedcontrol

I've added a UISegmentedControl to a UINavigation Bar, and when I tried to add a UIBarButtonItem programmatically in viewDidLoad viewController using the following code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *timeTableBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueRoundRect"]
                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                       target:self
                                       action:@selector(popUpTimeTable)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = timeTableBarButton;
```

There are no button showing at all. I wonder since I already have a UISegmentedControl, is it possible to do so?[image]

Comment: tryonce with out image add the new  **UIBarButtonItem**

Comment: You will get .check your image name exists or not .

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I add a system style UIBarButtonItem and still nothing appears.

Comment: @Uma The image name do exist.

Comment: Try adding in storyboard itself .It might come.

Comment: I can add a bar button in storyboard but I cannot link it to any file. I think it may because that the segmented control manages two view controllers, so the bar button do not know which VC it belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add the Bar button in navigation bar and there is no way your segment control should be blocking right bar button item. Please make sure that your self.navigationItem is not nil.

Comment: It really isn't nil. I think it may because that the segmented control manages two view controllers, so the bar button do not know which VC it belongs to.

Comment: Are you adding bar button to the navigation bar(main controller) or the controllers connected to specific segment control actions.